Why do some fields in the Go structs generated using cgo become anonymous?
I'm developing using a third-party SDK, but I've encountered an issue related to CGO conversion.
this C struct from third-party SDK,
C struct
typedef struct PicHead
{
    unsigned short Flag;
    unsigned char Version[16];
    unsigned int HeadSize;
    int64_t FileSize;
    unsigned int Macrograph;
    unsigned int PersonInfor;
    unsigned int Hierarchy;
    unsigned int SrcWidth;
    unsigned int SrcHeight;
    unsigned int SliceWidth;
    unsigned int SliceHeight;
    unsigned int ThumbnailWidth;
    unsigned int ThumbnailHeight;
    unsigned char Bpp;
    unsigned char Quality;
    J_COLOR_SPACE ColrSpace;
    float Scale;
    double Ruler;
    unsigned int Rate;
    long long ExtraOffset;
    long long TileOffset;
     ImageFormat SliceFormat;
    unsigned char HeadSpace[48];
}PicHead;

And this Go struct generated by CGO.
type _Ctype_struct_PicHead struct {
    Flag        _Ctype_ushort
    Version     [16]_Ctype_uchar
    _       [48]byte
    Bpp     _Ctype_uchar
    Quality     _Ctype_uchar
    ColrSpace   _Ctype_J_COLOR_SPACE
    Scale       _Ctype_float
    _       [8]byte
    Rate        _Ctype_uint
    ExtraOffset _Ctype_longlong
    TileOffset  _Ctype_longlong
    SliceFormat _Ctype_ImageFormat
    HeadSpace   [48]_Ctype_uchar
}

Some fields have been merged into a _  [48]byte and _   [8]byte.
I want to know why this happens and how to fix it.
my go version
go version go1.21.1 linux/amd64

and go env
GOTOOLCHAIN='auto'
GOTOOLDIR='/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64'
GOVCS=''
GOVERSION='go1.21.1'
GCCGO='gccgo'
GOAMD64='v1'
AR='ar'
CC='gcc'
CXX='g++'
CGO_ENABLED='1'
GOMOD='/dev/null'
GOWORK=''
CGO_CFLAGS='-O2 -g'
CGO_CPPFLAGS=''
CGO_CXXFLAGS='-O2 -g'
CGO_FFLAGS='-O2 -g'
CGO_LDFLAGS='-O2 -g'
PKG_CONFIG='pkg-config'
GOGCCFLAGS='-fPIC -m64 -pthread -Wl,--no-gc-sections -fmessage-length=0 -ffile-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build3219558694=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches'


This question is similar to: Golang: Export C fields to be externally visible using CGo. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Jean-BaptisteYunès
Thank you for your help. I checked the links you provided and tried them. I also updated the issues in my post.

"C struct fields that cannot be expressed in Go, such as bit fields or misaligned data, are omitted in the Go struct, replaced by appropriate padding to reach the next field or the end of the struct." cgo command

I wonder what happens if in the C struct you temporarily replace that int64_t type with an 8 byte array or something. The trouble seems to happen "around" that field as a lot of unsigned int fields are for some reason thrown away while the tool clearly supports them looking at that Rate field which did survive the conversion.
